# How to search through a set(list) using if statement with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, set

I'm trying to search through a large list and from what I gather, it's super fast to use a set rather than a normal list. My struggle is to use an if statement combined with regex to find the string in the list.

I've tried the following:

```
import re
search = re.compile('\[edit\s')

if search in set(list):
   print('found')
```

I created a list that has '[edit interfaces]' as an element but it doesn't seem to locate it.

Comment: "I'm trying to search through a large list and from what I gather, it's super fast to use a set rather than a normal list." That's for hash-based membership testing. If you have to iterate through everything anyway, it's not going to save you any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for

```
search = re.compile('\[edit\s')

l1 =  ["that", '[edit interfaces]', "that"]

for v in set(l1):
   if re.search(search, v):
       print('found ' + v)
```

You have to check the elements of the set to see if they match the regular expression. You can just do that with a simple check inside the for loop.

Comment: This doesn't really speed things up. I mean, potentially, if there were *many* duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can omit changing the list to a set and instead use python's build in filter function.

```
import re
search = re.compile('\[edit\s')

l1 =  ["that", '[edit interfaces]', "that"]

res = filter(lambda x : re.search(search, x), l1)

print(list(res))
```

This method avoids looping through the list and uses python built in functions which are fast.

Comment: Is this the kind of solution that you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, Philip. I think so.. Both your solutions are good. I just wonder which one is the fastest... From what you say, it looks like using filter is faster...

Comment: Why does the elements in the list disappear after you do a first lookup?

Comment: >>> res = filter(lambda x : re.search(search, x), l1)
>>> len(list(res))
1
>>> len(list(res))
0

Comment: This is because filter returns an iterator. When you call list(result), it basically runs through the whole iterator (result is the iterator). So when you call it the second time. Result is simply the empty iterator. I hope this clarification helps.